# Is "hat notation" for unit vectors commonly used in mathematics?

Tags: notation, vector-calculus

As an undergraduate, I clearly remember learning and using "hat notation" to describe unit vectors.  That is, if $\vec{v}$ is any vector (in 2 or 3 dimensions) then $\hat{v}$ denotes the unit vector in the direction $\vec{v}$, i.e.
$$\hat{v} = \frac{\vec{v}}{|\vec{v}|}$$

The "hat" was also used for the standard unit vectors in the direction of the $x$-, $y$-, and $z$-coordinate axes:
$$\hat{i}=\langle 1,0,0 \rangle,\quad \hat{j}=\langle 0,1,0\rangle, \quad \hat{k}=\langle 0,0,1\rangle$$

Now that I am teaching multivariable calculus for the first time, I see no use of this notation in our textbook (Stewart, 8th Ed.), and I am wondering if this notational convention is something I picked up from my undergraduate Physics coursework.  (Just to avoid misunderstanding:  Stewart uses boldface $\bf{i}$,$\bf{j}$,$\bf{k}$ for the unit vectors but does not use the hat accent.)  So my questions:

> Is "hat notation" for unit vectors (including the standard unit vectors, but not limited to them) widely used in teaching multivariable calculus, or is this something only physicists use?  Are there math textbooks that use it?

**Edited to add:** I thought I would mention the main reason I'm interested in this notation:  it makes certain formulas involving projection much simpler.  For example, if $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are any two vectors then
$$\operatorname{proj}_{\vec{u}}\vec{v} = \vec{v} \cdot \hat{u}$$
$$\operatorname{comp}_{\vec{u}}\vec{v} = \left(\vec{v} \cdot \hat{u}\right) \hat{u} $$

(compare $\frac{\vec{v} \cdot \vec{u}}{|\vec{u}|}$ and $\frac{\vec{v} \cdot \vec{u}}{|\vec{u}|^2}\vec{u}$, respectively).  Likewise the angle between any two vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ is given by $\cos(\theta) = \hat{u} \cdot \hat{v}$.

Comment: As far as I can tell it's not "standard" in calculus text books I've seen (Stewert, Apex, Wittman, Strang) but it does get taught. I certainly use the notation for unit vectors when teaching and I know several of my colleague do. It may be more standard in linear algebra.

Comment: It's really hard to write boldface i,j,k in homework and on tests. I tend to use $\hat{x},\hat{y}, \hat{z}$ in place of the quaternionic notation. That said, I haven't seen the beautiful notation $\vec{A} = A \hat{A}$ notation much used in math texts. You're probably correct about the physics influence, it is where I learned it.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook  Sure, I guess I assumed it goes without saying that boldface only works in printed books.  For me the question is whether you use $\vec{i}$ or $\hat{i}$, etc.

Comment: I don’t know how I picked it up if it’s not, but we briefly mention unit vectors in the precalc classes I teach, and I use it for the class (even though, indeed, it’s not in the book). Dotless $\hat{\imath}$ via `\hat{\imath}` for style points, of course :)

Comment: Perhaps it is "common" in physics or engineering, not mathematics.

Comment: I live in Belgium, I never saw this notation.

Comment: It's definitely common in physics, even at the higher levels. I've personally never seen the notation in higher (graduate) level math courses, it seems to be so fundamentally how we think about vectors spaces that it's no longer remarkable. So maybe it isn't taught in math because it isn't used at the higher levels.

Comment: That notation is definitely uncommon in mathematics. Generally speaking, mathematicians tend not to use special notations for different types of objects (which is a poor choice, in my opinion).

Comment: @mweiss ha ha, yes, my point is merely that bold face notation which cannot be written is probably not the best notation for undergraduates. It's silly, but, distinguishing between vectors and scalars is a task that too many of them tend to struggle with. I think it's best for us to use the same notation in texts as we expect them to use in their solutions. Sorry, I don't mean to distract from your actual question.

Comment: I thought the "hat" worked like this:  The standard unit vectors in the direction of the $x$-, $y$-, and $z$-coordinate axes would be called $\hat{x}, \hat{y},\hat{z}$

Comment: @GeraldEdgar The notation is not limited to the base vectors, but it's used for any unit vector. For instance, in Newton or Coulomb's laws one would typically denote the unit vector in the direction of the line joining two particle centers by $\hat{r}$.

Comment: I use $\hat{x}$ notation with my physics students. The part I love is trying to convince them that $\hat{x}$ doesn't have units of meters. Hey, it's even called a unit vector, so it must have units, right? They also tend to write $x$ and $\hat{x}$ interchangeably and not to understand that there is any difference between the coordinate and the unit vector. It's also amusing when I ask them to compute $\hat{x}\times\hat{y}$ and they insist on doing it by writing down a determinant, even though I walk them through many examples with the right-hand rule.

Comment: In applied maths (ie basically physics) we occasionally used this notation or one like it (but mainly for a basis). In pure maths (linear algebra) we used normal letters with no adornment for all vectors, matrices and scalars. When I learnt multivariable calculus we didn’t use duh notation: we used a bold letter (written as a letter with a wavy underline or sometimes a straight one) for a vector and the letter with no underline for its magnitude. But we didn’t have special notation for unit vectors in that direction. Reason is to differentiate there are lots of steps, even with suffix notation

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't say it's common (none of the calculus books on my shelf use it).  It's in some math books (e.g., [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=HVSVAwAAQBAJ&) one, and [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=Xlc0DwAAQBAJ&) one and [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=bXzAlkODwa8C&) one) but it's mostly in physics books.

Answer (score 0):

Echoing other comments and @ncr's answer: this notational convention is not unknown, but is not common in mathematical contexts.

Perhaps more to the point, although relatively experienced math people might guess what is intended, they'd need to *ask* to proceed with confidence, so whatever time was thought to be saved by the convenient notation might be lost by having to answer questions about it.

Also, the very-very-common convention to use "hat" for Fourier transform should give the Fourier-transform use vast precedence over a relatively trivial use of giving the unit vector corresponding to a vector, in my opinion. (The fact that people typically talk about vectors for a while before learning about Fourier transforms doesn't alter my opinion. It's not good to have *temporary* notation that becomes wildly misleading soon after.)

Comment: Well, the context between vectors and Fourier transforms is usually quite different. For instance, physicists frequently use the hat also to denote operators in quantum mechanics. It's also worth noting that the hat to denote Fourier transforms is seldom used outside mathematics. In engineering it is common to use lower-case letters for time-dependent quantities and upper-case letter for transformed quantities. Sometimes, tilde or calligraphic letters are used in physics and engineering to denote Fourier transform.

Comment: As I said once to my students in a class about sensors where we had to discuss many different quantities: "Guys, we have no way to not reuse notation; I don't like using same symbols for different quantities, but we have too many of them with established overlapping symbols, so pay attention at the context!"

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano, I interpreted the question as asking about mathematics proper... Yes, context is always the wisest determiner, certainly, but in my experience there is rarely a need for a special notation for the corresponding unit vector. Yes, also in mathematics proper it is sometimes useful to denote Fourier (or other spectral transforms) as letters rather than diacritical marks, of course, but "hat"'s use is incessant.